# How to ignore the exception in flutter integration test & continue the test execution

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-integration-test, flutter-exception

I'm getting `FirebaseException` is CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK, while flutter integration test is being run.!

Can anybody help in understading how to ignore the `FirebaseException` in integration test and continue the rest of execution?

I tried below walkaround,

```html
Future<void> restoreFlutterError(Future<void> Function() call) async {
  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails data) {
    if (data.exception is FirebaseException) {
      return;
    }
    FlutterError.presentError(data);
  };
}
```

And called above method in `testWidgets` by

```html
testWidgets('test execution', (tester) async {
    await restoreFlutterError(() async {
      app.main();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 10));
    });
    ...
    ...
});
```

But getting below error.!

```
 A test overrode FlutterError.onError but either failed to return it to its original state, or had unexpected additional errors that it could not handle. Typically, this is caused by using expect() before restoring FlutterError.onError.
```

Any helps appreciated.!

Comment: I run into the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to ignore exceptions by modifying FlutterError.onError function. Something like this worked for me:

```
 Future<void> ignoreException(Type exceptionType) async {
   final originalOnError = FlutterError.onError!;
  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    final currentError = details.exception.runtimeType;
    if (currentError == exceptionType) {
      return;
    }
    originalOnError(details);
  };
}
```

Later calling it in testWidgets like this, depending on the Exception thrown that you want to ignore:

```
await ignoreException(NetworkImageLoadException);
```